# Embedding finite dimensional subspaces of Schatten p-classes

Tags: banach-spaces, operator-theory

I have recently read a paper by Talagrand: Embedding subspaces of $L_{1}$ into $l^{N}_{1}$, and part of the chapter: Finite dimensional subspaces of $L_{p}$, written by Jonson and Schechtman. The theory of finite dimensional subspaces of $L_{p}$ is beautiful and fruitful, which has been well studied.

It is quite natural to expect similar results for noncommutative Lp spaces (or, more specifically, the Schatten p-classes, denoted by $S_{p}$). However, it seems that the theory of finite dimensional subspaces of Schatten p-classes is not well developed.

So, I am pretty interested in this topic. Are there any related references to embedding finite dimensional subspaces of $S_{p}$ into $S^{N}_{p}$? And what is the difficulty of such investigations in noncommutative settings?

PS: $S_{p}$ (resp. $S^{N}_{p}$) is the space of all infinite (resp. $N\times N$) matrices equipped with the Schatten-p norm $\|A\|_{p}=(Tr(|A|^{p}))^{1/p}$ with $|A|=(A^{*}A)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See

Schechtman, Gideon (IL-WEIZ)
Three observations regarding Schatten p classes. (English summary)
J. Operator Theory 75 (2016), no. 1, 139–149.
46B28 (47B10)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind suggestions, Prof. Johnson. In Section 3 of ”Three observations...” , Schechtman shown that only if $n\geq D^{\frac{-2p}{|p-2|k}}$, $l_{p}^{k}$ can be linearly embedded into $C_{p}^{n}$ with distortion at most $D$.

This result is quite related to my question. However, I prefer to look for investigations of the following specific problem: Given $\varepsilon>0$ and $n$-dimensional subspace $X\subseteq C_{p}$, what is the smallest $N(\varepsilon,n)$ such that there exists a subspace $Y\subseteq C_{p}^{N(\varepsilon,n)}$ such that $d_{B-M}(X, Y)<1+\varepsilon$?